# Closed form of a double series (gradient of a solution of the Laplace equation)

Tags: sequences-and-series, partial-differential-equations

Does anyone have an idea if this double sum could be simplified?

$$\sum_{p=0}^\infty\sum_{q=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^p(-1)^q}{(2p+1)(2q+1) } e^{-\pi\sqrt{(2p+1)^2+(2q+1)^2} \bar y}\sqrt{(2p+1)^2+(2q+1)^2}$$

(Context: I computed the electric potential, solution of Laplace's equation, in some geometry as a double cosine series, then the electric field E as -grad(potential), and this double sum is one of the terms in E evaluated at a specific location)

Thanks for any clue!